# How to reduce POSIXct time to previous 15-second interval for multiple time stamps in R

Tags: r, datetime, intervals, posixct

I have a bunch of time stamps ( that are in a POSIXct format.  The following are some examples of the timestamps I have:

```
2017-01-20 16:44:02
2017-01-20 17:14:59
2017-01-20 17:17:21
```

I am trying to get the timestamp reduced to the previous 15-second interval (00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45) so the following timestamps will be as follows:

```
2017-01-20 16:44:02 -> 2017-01-20 16:44:00
2017-01-20 17:14:59 -> 2017-01-20 17:14:45
2017-01-20 17:17:21 -> 2017-01-20 17:17:15
```

I have not worked much with the POSIXct format and don't know an efficient way to do this.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIXt values are stored as the number of seconds since an origin date (1970-01-01). You can use that fact and some modulus arithmatic to round your values. Here's a function that can help

```
round_15 <- function(x) {
  xs <- as.numeric(x)
  x - xs %% 15
}

x <- as.POSIXct(c("2017-01-20 16:44:02","2017-01-20 17:14:59","2017-01-20 17:17:21"))
x
# [1] "2017-01-20 16:44:02 EST" "2017-01-20 17:14:59 EST"
# [3] "2017-01-20 17:17:21 EST"
round_15(x)
# [1] "2017-01-20 16:44:00 EST" "2017-01-20 17:14:45 EST"
# [3] "2017-01-20 17:17:15 EST"
```

Basically we just subtract whatever number of seconds is left over after we divide by 15.

Answer (score 0):

Package [`datetimeutils`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=datetimeutils), which I maintain, has a function `roundPOSIXt`:

```
timestamps <- as.POSIXct(c("2017-01-20 16:44:02",
                           "2017-01-20 17:14:59",
                           "2017-01-20 17:17:21"))

library("datetimeutils")
roundPOSIXt(timestamps, "15 sec")

## [1] "2017-01-20 16:44:00 CET" "2017-01-20 17:14:45 CET"
## [3] "2017-01-20 17:17:15 CET"
```